# Entity Framework merge data from classes

Tags: entity-framework, class, abstract

I have a abstract class "Movement" and two concrete classes "Revenue" and "Expenses".

Movement has common properties for those concrete classes and each concrete class has its own properties.

I would like to read from the Movement repository but also have the concretes' classes properties. There is only 1 table to read, but reading Movement repository only gives me - obviously - the Movement's properties.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your code and DB structure it's hard to say what exactly you need to do to load related objects, You may need to go through this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb896272(v=vs.100).aspx) article.

In example below "Include" is used to load another entity in the graph,

```
// Define a LINQ query with a path that returns 
// orders and items for a contact.
var contacts = (from contact in context.Contacts
              .Include("SalesOrderHeaders.SalesOrderDetails")
                select contact).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also there are different types of loading,

- Lazy Loading
- Eager Loading
- Explicitly Loading

More could be read at this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) article.